# Can you backdate posts in Meta Business Suite?

Tags: meta-business-suite

> Backdating gives you the ability to make a new post appear as if it
> was published in the past. To do this, click the arrow next to
> **Publish**, then click **Backdate**. Then select the preferred time and click
> **Backdate**.

While Facebook's Business Manager/Creator Studio supports **backdating**<sup>[[1]](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/2223502627919449)[[2]](https://www.facebook.com/business/learn/lessons/schedule-draft-backdate-expiration-dates-posts)</sup>, they seem to have completely removed this option from the new Meta Business Suite. Is there a way to do it anyway?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found is to:

1. Create the post **without** backdating.
2. Go back, click the post's settings (3 dots) and choose **Edit date**.
3. Choose the backdate and click **Done**.

Between the seconds and minutes it takes to do it users will be able to see the original date, so try not to stall...

[image: Facebook Post's Edit date]